# Logging in with Stack Exchange OpenID from the "Ask Question" page cause the question to be lost

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, stack-exchange-openid

I recently prepped a question on a site which I had not yet created an account on. After preparing the question and clicking 'Log in', I logged in as normal, but then was prompted to create the new account. After creating the new account, I was directed to the main question list, instead of back to my question. Luckily I was able to retrieve my text using the bfcache, but it is obviously not an ideal workflow.

Repro steps:

1. Have an existing SE account.
2. Without logging in, prepare a new question on a site you haven't created an account on before.
3. Click the 'Log in' link displayed in the New Question form.
4. Confirm creation of the account ("Confirm Your New Account" prompt).
5. Get redirected to the front page of the site.

Comment: No repro on `ham.stackexchange.com` (beta site) and `diy.stackexchange.com` (non beta site) by following your steps. On both sites, after clicking "Confirm and create this account" I was automatically taken back to my question with the text there. This was with a Google login - which did you use?

Comment: This was with an SE network login. I'll try to repro again on a new site.

Comment: Just tested on mathematics, and repro'd once again. The 'Confirm and create' prompt redirected me to http://math.stackexchange.com/?newreg=blahblahblah, which displayed the front page of mathematics.

Comment: Yep, exactly that ^. Me reproed. With SE login.

Comment: So, this is a bug with the Stack Exchange OpenID provider ignoring some arguments telling it where to redirect when finished.

Comment: This is [now fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261964/login-process-deletes-question), you can use your diamond to mark it [tag:status-completed] as well. :)

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: As confirmed by my tests and images (below) and alienth's and nicael's reproducing:

- Google login - Problem not present
- Facebook login - Unknown, requires testing
- SE Login - Problem confirmed as per alienth's question/bug report

---

Using: Debian 8.0; Iceweasel 31.7.0; Google account login;

Attempts made: `ham.stackexchange.com` (beta site); `diy.stackexchange.com` (non beta site); `android.stackexchange.com` (non beta site);

### Step 1

Type a question.

[image: step1]

---

### Step 2

Click "log in".

[image: step2]

---

### Step 3

Choose "Login with Google".

[image: step3]

---

### Step 4

Click "Confirm and Create This Account".

[image: step4]

---

### Step 5

After completing step 4 I'm automatically returned to the question with the text still there.
Account was created ok, and I'm logged in fine - with the +100 associated bonus rep, etc.

[image: step5]

Comment: Looks like it may be limited to SE login. Another user did comment saying he was able to repro using SE.

Comment: @alienth Looks that way. You'd think it would be the same redirect script for them all, but obviously not... (or something is different anyway..)

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem only with SE login.