# Login process deletes question

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

When posting a question on a SE site you don't have a SE account on yet, logging in can take you to the main page, instead of posting your question, if you're not careful. Users who do not know about the auto-save feature may get the impression that their question is now lost.

A minor issue.

To reproduce:

- Go to a Stack Exchange site you don't have an account on yet
- After creating your question, scroll down and click "sign up using Stack Exchange" (incorrectly, yes; but it is super easy to overread)
- On the next page, realize your error and choose "already have an account? Log in"
- Log in and/or create a SE account on this new site

You will be taken on the main page of the SE site, instead of your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging in with Stack Exchange OpenID from the "Ask Question" page cause the question to be lost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259726/logging-in-with-stack-exchange-openid-from-the-ask-question-page-cause-the-que)

Comment: @ShadowWizard not a duplicate; broadly related, at best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; that isn't ideal, and will be resolved (preserving the `?returnUrl`) in the next build.

Comment: What about [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251982/login-not-redirecting-back-to-page-where-login-link-was-clicked-if-account-creat)? Also fixed while fixing this bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard pretty sure that should work...